# Renaming Google Slides Presentation (google slides API)

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I'm trying to figure out how to rename a google slides presentation (ie. the document, not an individual slide). I've gone through a good amount of the [Google Slide API Request documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#Request), but am still struggling to find the correct request. In my example, the objective is to rename the google presentation to "hello-world".

Being that I can't locate the right fields, when i go to execute the code below I keep receiving the following error:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/[PRESENTATION ID]:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Presentation" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0]', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Presentation" at \'requests[0]\': Cannot find field.'}]}]">
```

I've tried playing around with the request as much as possible, but still can't seem to figure it out. Provided below is the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
slides_service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
presentationId = '####'   

body = {
  "requests": [{    
    "Presentation": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "description": "hello-world",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}

response = slides_service.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId=presentationId,body=body).execute()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably it can be done via API Google Drive rather than Slides.

Comment: Thank you @YuriKhristich!

Answer (score 1):

As per Yuri mentioned, Drive API would be much more reasonable instead.

#### Code:

```
new_title = 'hello-world'
file = {'title': new_title}
response = service.files().patch(fileId=file_id,
                                 body=file,
                                 fields='title').execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Python Sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch#python)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with this @NaziA. The code example is very appreciated too!

Comment: You are welcome @LiamClifford, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Absolutely, I just up voted your answer. I don’t think I have enough reputation yet to where my response will show (but it did mention that my response was recorded). Thanks again for the help with this!